# Copy data from datagrid to Excel and open the file without saving it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, visual-studio-2003

I'm working on VS 2003 C# WINFORM.

I want where I click the button, the datagrid (not datagridView) will be copied in the Excel file and it will be opened (with data of course) then the user will choose if he want to save it after the analyse or not.

```
                try
                { 
                    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                    sfd.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
                    sfd.FilterIndex = 1 ;
                    sfd.RestoreDirectory = true ;
                    sfd.Title = "Liste des différés";
                    sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        if(sfd.FileName.Length > 0)
                        {
                            string data = null;
                            int i = 0;
                            int j = 0; 

                            Excel.Application xlApp ;
                            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
                            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
                            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                            xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
                            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                            for (i = 0; i <= dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                            {
                                for (j = 0; j <= dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                                {
                                    data = dsSelectionListeDiffere.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                                }
                            }


                            // Pass the full path to the SaveAs method
    //                      string fullPathName = Path.Combine(folderName, "csharp.xls");
                            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileNames, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                            xlApp.Quit();

                            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                            releaseObject(xlApp);


                        }

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }



private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: You will need to save the excel file before opening it in excel.

Comment: no it's not what i search , i wnat to copy the datagrid (or dataset) to an excel file and open it at the same time when i click a button . thank you

Comment: this is my code for exportng data to Excel with DialogBox :

Comment: sorry if it's not well organized

Comment: i want to diplay the excel file with data inside , and the user will choose after if he want to save it or he wanted just to see it .Thank you

Comment: @Meryem, rather edit your question to insert the code there, not as a comment

Comment: this code is working but actually i dont want to save the file but just to read datagrid (dataset) in a excel file and then i can save it if i want . thank you